# Crystal Report formula value from a group cannot be passed to another group

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

Above is my crystal report.
The `@NetSalary` formula is `{@IncomeForPaye}-{@TotalDeductions}`

{@IncomeForPaye}  and {@TotalDeductions} shows their values correctly in group footer 3.But in group footer 2 they dont show any values but NULL/EMPTY.
[These two fields are suppressed depending on the group 03 
values (Earn -E,Deduct-D,Savings-S accordingly]

Is it not possible to pass those values between groups?

Can I use a global variable for them? and how?

Comment: show the formulas for {@IncomeForPaye} and {@TotalDeductions}

Comment: {@IncomeForPaye}={@LessDirections}+{@TotalIncome};

{@TotalIncome}---->if({command.EARN_DEDUCT}="E") then
{@TotalGrossPay}+Sum ({@Amount}, {command.EARN_DEDUCT})

{@LessDirections}----> Assume always zero for the moment since it has not been initialzed yet.

{@TotalDeductions}----->if({command.EARN_DEDUCT}="D") then Sum ({@Amount}, {command.EARN_DEDUCT}) else 0.00